# onConfigurationChanged() is not being called on orientation change

Tags: java, android, orientation, android-relativelayout, onconfigurationchanged

I saw some related questions on SO, but I'm not able to resolve my issue.
I've created separate layout for PORTRAIT and LANDSCAPE mode.

I've modified the `AndroidManifest.xml` file for corresponding orientation change but `onConfigurationChanged()` is not working when I'm implementing it in activity.

Now the issue is at **`layout.addView(graphView, lp);`** in `onCreate()`.
I've written absolute hard-coded value in `GraphView` class.

So it works perfectly foe PORTRAIT mode but graphView is not correctly placed when I switch to LANDSCAPE mode.

To resolve this I've created `GraphViewLand` class which is coded exclusively for LANDSCAPE mode. But it is not getting called from `onConfigurationChanged()`.

Rest of the layout is coming perfectly as I've created separate `main.xml` file for each orientation. But since `graphView` is created programmatically, it is not placed properly.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

I just read this from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance):

For any types of configuration changes you say that you handle there, you will receive a call to your current activity's onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) method instead of being restarted. **If a configuration change involves any that you do not handle, however, the activity will still be restarted and onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) will not be called.**

**onCreate() method**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    init();

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, btnindex.getId());

    GraphView graphView = new GraphView(this, values, "CurrentGraph",
                horlabels, verlabels);
    layout.addView(graphView, lp);
    }
```

**onConfigurationChanged() method**

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Log.v("LAND", "SCPAE");
    }
}
```

*Any help appriciated :)*

Comment: what is the `.manifest` file? Do you mean `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create two different types of view (for landscape and portrait) in xml and you have to write logic on different types of view then donot use `android:configChanges` in manifest.

***If you have no `android:configChanges` in manifest and you have different sets of layout for landscape and portrait then when you change orientation your control will come to onCreate()*** inside that method you can write your logic.

Comment: okay, so do I need to implement `onConfigurationChanged()` method?

Comment: No you don't need too, but since the activity is destroyed and created you should save and restore application state properly to give the application context back to user.

Comment: With Bundle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state, With onRetainNonConfigurationInstance (never tried...) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Some code example in exercice 3 of notepad tuto (not dedicated to configuration changes): http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html

Comment: @Vince but 1st link from former comment explains about saving variables like boolean,String.etc to retrieve. I want to retrieve the state.

Comment: Yes the state of your application is the sum of all its data in memory, at the end it's a list of simple type variable. If your code have classes you can code a save and restore code inside each one (ie serialization/deserialization system)

Answer (score 1):

Did you code onConfigurationChanged as an **override** in your **Activity** class?
Basic override:

```
// Called on rotation. 
    // Does not call onDestroy anymore due to android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" in manifest
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

My manifest declaration for info:

```
<activity android:name=".Slime"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Comment: My application is always oriented as landscape. I've overriden the method to disable auto orientation. I had some code before in the overrided onConfigurationChanged but there is no more. I posted this because with only this 2 code addition it worked for me.

Comment: It can not, application is always run as landscape

Comment: I'm using too a library called cocos2d-android, and i call a utility method to force landscape (for safety...): https://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d/blob/master/cocos2d-android/src/org/cocos2d/nodes/CCDirector.java#L278 theApp is Activity: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)

Comment: What do you mean with that: If I write android:screenOrientation="landscape" in my manifest and then launch the app in portrait mode, it is working

Comment: The hard requirement you pointed before is just an hardware requirement for market filter. I can't remember for emulator i would have to try but don't have one here. I think it works nice in emulator. I keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

How do you say that the `onConfigurationChanged()` method is not called? Is the log not being printed? Isn't the toast being shown?

Secondly, you mention that the issue is at `layout.addView` in `onCreate()`. Do note that if `android:configChanges` is present in your manifest, then `onCreate()` is not called on orientation change. You need to move the piece of code that programmatically modifies the UI layout into the `onConfigurationChanged()` method.

Comment: yup exactly. Log is not getting printed and I'm not even getting the toast. But if I don't write code for adding graphView in `onCreate()`, how my `graphView` will be displayed? So I'm calling `graphView` in `onCreate()` and another class i.e. `graphViewLand` in `onConfigurationChanged()` but it's not getting called.

Comment: If you are not even seeing the logs, then the second part of my answer is irrelevant. I suggest you look at Sunil Kumar Sahoo's answer to this question. That is more relevant to your case.